# uncheck the checkbox upon saving a row

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, jqgrid

I am using a jqgrid and whenever I check a check box the row is editable but I have 2 issues:

1. After editing the row the checkbox is still checked but I want it to be unchecked upon entering enter and saving the row ..
2. I want to click on one checkbox at a time

here is my code

```js
dataGrid.prototype = {

  display: function() {
    var self = this;
    var html = [];
    var check = 0;
    var lastSelection;
    html.push("<table id='" + this.id + "" + "'class='table'>\n</table>");
    html.push("<div id='pagger_" + this.id + "'></div>");
    $('body').append(html.join(""));
    $("#" + this.id).jqGrid({
      url: "index.jsp",
      styleUI: 'Bootstrap',
      .....
      loadComplete: function() {
        $("#" + this.id).on("click", "input[type=checkbox]", function(e) {
          var $this = $(this); //this is the checkbox
          var rowid = $this.parents('tr').attr('id');
          self.editRow(rowid);

        });
      }


    });
  },

  .....

  editRow: function(id) {
    var lastSelection;
    if (id && id !== lastSelection) {
      $("#" + this.id).jqGrid('restoreRow', lastSelection);
      $("#" + this.id).jqGrid('editRow', id, {
        keys: true,
        focusField: 1
      });
      lastSelection = id;
    }
  }

};
```

Comment: In the loadcomplete, `this` is not what you think it is. Save a copy like you did with self and use that

Answer (score 0):

If you have only (1) checkbox, you can put something like `$('#your_checkbox').prop('checked',false);` after the save function. Or if you have multiple checkboxes, you can put something like this `$('#your_form input').prop('checked',false);`.

Comment: the same problem still ocuurs

Answer (score 0):

In the Save button click put like this if you are unchecking single check box $("#checkbox_Id").attr("checked",false).If you will use multiplecheckboxes use the class of check boxes to uncheck all checkboxes
$(".checkbox_class").attr("checked",false)